# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found -- unknown column 'base.status' in 'field list' in node edit

Tags: drupal-7

Running Drupal 7.39 with PHP v 5.3.17 and database fully updated.
The problem: Cannot edit any nodes. Clicking EDIT triggers the PDOException error.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.status' in 'field list': SELECT base.rid AS rid, base.hash AS hash, base.type AS type, base.uid AS uid, base.source AS source, base.source_options AS source_options, base.redirect AS redirect, base.redirect_options AS redirect_options, base.language AS language, base.status_code AS status_code, base.count AS count, base.access AS access, base.status AS status FROM {redirect} base WHERE (base.redirect = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => node/201 ) in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 198 of /srv/www/htdocs/includes/entity.inc).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have drush installed, run the following:

```
drush sqlq 'update system set schema_version=7100 where name="redirect"'
drush updb -y
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2578019